# Is it possible to turn gps ground speed and vehical heading to acceleration and yaw angle in NED

Tags: matlab, math, localization, gps, calculation

I am searching the way to aid my **IMU** input (including acceleration(m/s^2) and angular speed(rad/s) on each axis) by using **ground** speed on each axis from GPS and Vehicle heading.

Is there any possible solution for this problem.

Thank you so much in advance for any kind of help.